# catch the end of the jiax request in jquery loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

do I capture all ajax requests at the end of the loop in the following code structure?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) { ?>
            $("#btn_fiyat<?php echo $key+1;?>").click(function(){
                form_id = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
                tum_inputlar = $("#"+form_id).find(":input");
                islem=false
                tum_inputlar.each(function(){
                    id= $(this).attr('data-id');
                    tarih= $(this).attr('data-tarih');
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/fiyat/ekle/<?php echo $id; ?>",
                        data: {tarih:tarih,id:id},
                        success:function(cevap){ 
                            islem=True;
                        }
                    });
                });
                if (islem==true) {
                    alert("ok");
                }
            });
        <?php } ?>

    });
</script>
```

Do I need to capture all ajax requests at the end of the loop in the following code structure?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are setting this ajax request for each input separately. In this case your approach won't have any sense, because of is used as part of loop. If you have such requirement(to do some stuff after all ajax requests ended) and you are using [ES6](http://es6-features.org) you can try to use it's great features called [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await).